# Dataframe to dictionary Python

Tags: python

I'm looking to turn two columns in a dataframe into a dictionary, column_a holds the item, and column_b has the description:

```
column_a     column_b
---------------------
Furniture    Table
Furniture    Chair
Tech         Laptop
Tech         Screen
```

And the result should be:

```
{'Furniture':['Table','Chair'], 'Tech' : ['Laptop', 'Screen']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a `groupby` statement, like this:

```
def turn_df_into_dict(df):
    
    output_dict = {}
    
    for name, group in df.groupby('column_a'):
        output_dict[name] = group['column_b']
        
    return output_dict
```

This should give you the intended output :)

Comment: Yep, that's good, however, it does not deal with repeated values in 'column_b' so I added a .unique() :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Group into a list and then convert to dict:

```
dct = df.groupby('column_a')['column_b'].apply(list).to_dict()
```